# Handling different responses with RESTful api's

Tags: c#, api, jwt

I have a `/login` endpoint on my api which takes a username and password to then return a result to the user. The result returned is like so:

```
public class SignInResult
{
   public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
   public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
   public bool IsNotAllowed { get; set; }
   public bool RequiresTwoFactor { get; set; }
}
```

My frontend then checks the `Succeeded` flag and if it has succeeded it will then call of to `token/request` which will then return a JWT.

Should I be returning `Forbidden 403` for scenarios when the user `IsNotAllowed` and when `Succeeded` is false and then `Unauthorized 401` for when the user `IsLockedOut`? Is the correct way of doing things with RESTful api's?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is generally the correct way of doing things. You can also add messages along with the HTTP status codes in order to explain the specific error. For a successful log-in, you should use HTTP 200, which comes in the form of the `Ok()` function. You should also return an object with the token, like so:

```
return Ok(new {token = GeneratedToken});
```

in the case of a successful login.

Comment: If that's correct, how would the frontend know that the user RequiresTwoFactor?

Comment: Send a specialized message with the 401

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its correct way. Some kind of responses generates automatically. For example, you get `Undocumented` with wrong api calls. Or you will get `Unauthorized` if you have authorize attribute

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : ControllerBase.
```

You can generate StatusCodes by your own.

```
return new JsonResult(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
```

You can find some information here https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1